# Widget Locations & Static Blocks (not working)

Tags: static-block, widgets

[image: Magento Widget]

As you can see in the image above I have created a widget that will display on a specific page which I defined and created the static block that the widget will load.  But I am only able to load the widget in certain Block references.

I have a sneaking suspicion that these block references are not activated in my theme.  If I am indeed right can someone please help me activate the blocks that I would like my widget to load into.  I want it to load just below the navigation but that option does not work currently.

If my suspicion is completely wrong and you have a fix for me please let me know.  Thank you - thank you - thank you, so much for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The "Page Top" block is defined in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml`:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="after_body_start" as="after_body_start" translate="label">
    <label>Page Top</label>
</block>
```

and rendered from the layout templates, such as `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/1column.phtml`:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
```

Since you have the option to choose "Page Top" and widget instances are associated with the theme, your theme seems to support the block, but maybe the templates don't render it. Check the phtml files in `app/design/frontend/[your package]/[your theme]/page/` and add the line if it's missing.